# Updating dictionary values of keys from a .txt file

Tags: python, dictionary

So I've created a dictionary off the txt file "PM.txt" where the key is the player and the value is their penalty minutes. I know dictionary keys have to be unique so how would I update the value of the key adding it to the current value, as the key exists more than once in the txt file.

```
    "PM.txt"
    Neil,2
    Paul,5
    Neil,10
    Santos,2
    Neil,2
    Santos,10
    Paul,2
    Alex,2
```

So far I have this which returns:

{'Alex': 2, 'Santos': 10, 'Paul': 2, 'Neil': 2}

```
    def pm_dict(filename):
        f = open(filename, 'r')
        dict = {}
        for line in f:
            x = line.split(",")
            player = x[0]
            minutes = x[1]
            c = len(minutes)-2
            minutes = minutes[0:c]
            dict[player] = minutes

        return dict
```

But how would I create a function or a helper for it to return:

{'Alex': 2, 'Santos': 12, 'Paul': 7, 'Neil': 14}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert your `minute` to `int`:

```
minutes = int(x[1])
```

Then you add it to your dictionary:

```
if player in dict:
  dict[player] += minutes
else:
  dict[player] = minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of standard libraries make this problem straightforward.  A `defaultdict` creates a key if it doesn't already exist of its default type, so you can use `D[key] += value` even when the key doesn't exist yet.  The `csv` module automatically parses .csv files.  the default separator is comma.  Also make sure not to use `dict` as a variable name.  It overwrites the `dict` type.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

def pm_dict(filename):
    D = defaultdict(int)
    with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as f:
        r = csv.reader(f)
        for key,value in r:
            D[key] += int(value)
    return dict(D) # converts back to a standard dict, but not required.

print(pm_dict('PM.txt'))
```

Output:

> ```
> {'Neil': 14, 'Paul': 7, 'Alex': 2, 'Santos': 12}
> ```

The values make more sense as numbers, but if you want value strings as in your example the last line of the function can be the following to convert values back to strings.  This is a *dictionary comprehension*.

```
return {k:str(v) for k,v in D.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your for loop, instead of dict[player] = minutes:

```
if player not in dict:
    dict[player] = 0

dict[player] += minutes
```

Also, instead of:

> ```
>         minutes = x[1]
>         c = len(minutes)-2
>         minutes = minutes[0:c]
> ```

You can do:

```
minutes = x[1].strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `defaultdict`:

```
def pm_dict(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    dict = defaultdict(int)
    for line in f:
        x = line.split(",")
        player = x[0]
        minutes = x[1]
        c = len(minutes)-2
        minutes = minutes[0:c]
        dict[player] += int(minutes)

    return dict
```

After refactoring:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
```

...

```
def get_penalty_minutes_dict(filename):
    result_dict = defaultdict(int)
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:           
       for player, minutes in csv.reader(f):
           result_dict[player] += int(minutes)

    return result_dict
```